# Issues with connecting Twilio Flex Digital Channels to Google Dialogflow CX

Tags: twilio

I have been following the blog post [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/flex-dialogflow-cx-digital) and I've made it to testing the function on my local environment. I've copy and pasted everything form the blog into my text editor. Nothing in my code is original - but I cannot get it to work! When I try to run it in my local environment, I get this error:

```
            const b = bindings[key].toString();
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at PathTemplate.render (/Users/dialogflow-cx/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:114:37)
    at SessionsClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath (/Users/dialogflow-cx/node_modules/@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx/build/src/v3/sessions_client.js:1237:75)
    at exports.handler (/Users/Waterfield/dialogflow-cx/functions/dialogflow-detect-intent.protected.js:21:25)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/dialogflow-cx/node_modules/@twilio/runtime-handler/dist/dev-runtime/internal/functionRunner.js:74:9)
    at process.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:917:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

I don't know where to go from here! Help!

Answer (score 1):

Here your TypeError is "cannot read properties of undefined", that means at least one of your passed arguments is undefined.
As we go through your return error, second line directs to the "projectLocationAgentSessionPath" and this section refers to the "Setup the detectIntentRequest" in the [blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/flex-dialogflow-cx-digital) .

```js
         session: client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
            context.DIALOGFLOW_CX_PROJECT_ID,
            context.DIALOGFLOW_CX_LOCATION,
            context.DIALOGFLOW_CX_AGENT_ID,
            event.dialogflow_session_id
        )
```

The above error means at least on of the objects that relates to `projectId`, `location`, `agentId`, `SessionId` is returning undefined.

To resolve the error you have to check whether you are passing correct environment variables the same as `.env` files or not?

Answer (score 0):

Within the error, we can see that there is a reference to the code you are working on:

```
    at exports.handler (/Users/Waterfield/dialogflow-cx/functions/dialogflow-detect-intent.protected.js:21:25)
```

This refers to this line:

```js
        client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
            context.DIALOGFLOW_CX_PROJECT_ID,
            context.DIALOGFLOW_CX_LOCATION,
            context.DIALOGFLOW_CX_AGENT_ID,
            event.dialogflow_session_id
        )
```

Following the code through the [dialogflow library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow-cx/blob/main/src/v3/sessions_client.ts#L1849-L1861) and then the [Google API extensions library](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs/blob/main/src/pathTemplate.ts#L132-L163) shows that ultimately the code is running through the keys of the object that relate to the `project`, `location`, `agent` and `session` which map to the 4 arguments above. And at least one of them is returning `undefined`.

Have you added the correct environment variables to your `.env` file? Are you passing a `dialogflow_session_id` when you make a request to test this endpoint?